# Cannot Access LDAPS from webbrowser on Hyper V virtual machine

Tags: ssl, ldap, x509certificate, hyper-v

We have an test environmnet where the physical AD server is set up for LDAPS connections and a Hyper V virtual machine running the webserver with our AD management web app loaded up.   We have set up the x509 certs on both the physical AD server and on the virtual webserver.   We are able to link to the AD server using SSl via Ldap.exe with no problems.  When we try to access through the web browser it fails to connect.   The event logs show an Schannel event with

> "The certificate received from the remote server was issued by an
>   untrusted certificate authority. Because of this, none of the data
>   contained in the certificate can be validated. The SSL connection
>   request has failed. The attached data contains the server
>   certificate."

If we try the same thing from two phyisical boxes it works fine and likewise if we try to access the AD server from a virtual machine without using LDAPS it works fine.

I have gone on to the server and via the certificate snap in deleted the hyper v virtual machine management's self signed trusted root cert and restarted the service with no change.   I can't find anything else relevent to our setup to try.

Anyone have any insight in to what we are missing on the virtual machine that is causing this failure?

Answer (score 0):

According to me the message :

"The certificate received from the remote server was issued by an untrusted certificate authority. Because of this, none of the data contained in the certificate can be validated. The SSL connection request has failed. The attached data contains the server certificate."

Indicates that you do not intstall the public key certificate of the certificate authority on your client (Virtual Web server) certificate repository.

Try to install it on computer repository, but also on  the reposository of the user which is in charge to start IIS.